# Facebook Connect auto-signon?

Tags: facebook

So with all these fancy new APIs and such that Facebook is making available, I've noticed that on the partner sites (Pandora, docs.com, etc.), there is no login---Facebook automatically signs you in. You don't even need to press a button to connect if you already have a FB session established.

Is this a feature of the new API? Or is this a Facebook partners-only feature? I haven't seen any information on whether this is possible for cool guys that don't run huge companies.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the Facebook blog?

http://blog.facebook.com/blog.php?post=383404517130

Comment: "We've worked with three pre-selected partners—Microsoft Docs, Yelp and Pandora—to give you a glimpse of this future, which you can access without having to login again or click to connect." That'd be it. Thanks a lot!